# Error Adding COM Reference In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, com, interop

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 that will not allow me to add COM Reference.  The Visual Studio COM browser does list the type library as being registered but, as soon as I attempt to add the reference, I get the error below.  Note, that the library is showing up as registered in Visual Studio type libraries section of COM.  Also noteworthy to mention is that I am able to add a reference to the library (Fuel Direct 1.0 Type Library) to a Visual Studio 2008 project without any issues.

Also, I have included another screen shot of a Visual Studio 2010 project that has a reference to the COM object that I am trying to add to another project.  If I remove the COM reference from the project and attempt to add the reference again it fails.  Any suggestions on things I might try?  I don't know whether or not this could be an issue with my Visual Studio environment or something else.  I used to be able to add a reference in Visual Studio 2010 up until this past Thursday and nothing drastic has changed on my system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio has found the type library in the registry (HKCR\TypeLib key) but when it tried to use it, it found out that it is missing a required key.  Reinstalling the COM server is advisable, after worrying for a while why the registry got messed up.

Comment: Hans, I tried re-installing the library a few times with no success.  However, when I manually add the xml to the project file it appears to work in a test app that i created.  the xml i added to the project file is below. <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="FuelDirectOLETLB">
      <Guid>{A3DC67F2-AAF5-49DE-908F-C9913A6E9060}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>1033</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Well, you are looking in the wrong place for the problem.  It is the registry that has the issue.  Use Regedit.exe to look at it.

Comment: Thanks your input Hans.  I have looked into the registry and there are numerous entries for the library.  But, I admittedly do not know exactly what to look for.  Are there a standard set of entries for a COM library that I should be looking for?  And, I still don't understand why I can add a reference to this library in VS 2008 but, it fails in VS 2010.